# Apache configuration: Regex to disable access to files/directories beginning with a dot

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to disable access to any file OR directory, whose name begins with a DOT. I came up with the following, but it disables access to files/directories beginning with DOT only if they are directly in the Document root.

```
<Files ~ "^\.|\/\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

With this,

```
http://my_server.com/.svn/entries   --> Permission denied
http://my_server.com/abcd/.svn/entries  --> Accessible, should be disabled
```

Whats the proper regex to achieve this?

Comment: This really should be built into the default configuration; .file is usually to hide it anyway (.htaccess for example)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You code does not work because `<Files>` only applies to the *basename* of the requested document. That is, the part after the last slash. (source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files)

Apache blocks `.htaccess` files in a default installation (better: all files starting with `.ht`). If you looked closely at the configuration files, you would see something like this:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

So to hide all files starting with a dot, you would use:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

In order to make it work for directories starting with a dot, use the following (tested) code:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^\.|\/\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Is there a way to test these regexes other than trial and error? They don't seem to follow the rules of Regex that I am familiar with. E.g. `^/protected/.*` matches /protected/file.txt and `^/(folder1|folder2)/.*` does not match /folder1/file.txt but `/folder1/.*` does.

Comment: I think the forward slash does not need to be escaped. Plus, the DirectoryMatch regex may be written in a more compact form as : `<DirectoryMatch "/\.">` or like the following to exclude the .well-known `<DirectoryMatch "/\.(?!well-known)">`. Remember to pay attention to the directory .well-known which is standardized and it should not be forbidden under normal circumstances.

Comment: @Timido You'd actually want that to be `/\.(?!well-known/)`, otherwise you'd allow access to any directory that starts with `.well-known` including `.well-known-abc`.

Answer (score 23):

```
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

This will deny from viewing any files or directories beginning with dot.
It affects any level in the paths tree.

[F] modifier at the end says to forbid access (no need for L modifier to say that it is Last rule to apply, it is implied by default).

The regular expression has two parts (any of them allowed to match, not required to be both):

```
(part1|part2)
```

The first part matches anything that starts from dot (for the case when you use it in per-directory .htaccess file and there will be no slash at the start of string we are matching on):

```
^\.
```

For example, this will work for `.test`, `.git/HEAD`
but will not work for `/.git`, `path/.hidden`.

The second part matches anything that contains slash followed by dot. This is useful if you have this rule in VirtualHost or in side-wide Apache configuration, in which a case string we match may begin with slash.

This rule will match: `/.git`, `some/.hidden`
This rule will not match: `.git`, `.hidden`

When we combine these both rules, it seems that we cover all possible cases.

Answer (score 8):

This works perfectly for me (Apache 2.4):

```
<LocationMatch "\/\.">
    Require all denied
</LocationMatch>
```

Denies any URL that contains a component beginning with a dot (file or directory).

Comment: `"/\."` That's enough!

Answer (score 3):

With rewrite mod:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404]
```

Every file or dir who begin with a dot will be redirected to 404.

```
/myDir/.svn => 404
/.gitignore => 404
/dir1/dir2/dir3/..../.toHide => 404
```